# Nested RecyclerView not scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having a problem adding a recycler view inside another recycler view. The child recycler is inside a CardView and the CardView is inside the parent recycler view. I tried all solutions on the internet and no use. I want the child recycler view to scroll vertically while the parent recycler view also scroll vertically.

Parent Recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundPrimary"
    tools:context=".BidsCenter">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bidCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Child recycler view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/r0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itemPreviewInCenter"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemTitleInCenter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/itemPreviewInCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/totalBidPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/numberOfBids"
                android:background="@drawable/bid_total"
                android:clickable="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latestBidDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bidMenu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/numberOfBids"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/latestBidDate"
                android:background="@drawable/new_message_count"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/text"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bidMenu"
                style="?android:attr/actionOverflowButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/showBidders"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/r0"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_margin="3dp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/latestBidsInCenter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

here are some screenshots

parent:
[image]

child:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Editted**

you have to disable parent recyclerView touch event while scrolling child 
Recyclerview

```
latestBidsInCenter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (v.getId() == child.getId()) {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                bidCenter.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            } else {
                bidCenter.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution didn't work. Btw, latestBidsInCenter is the child, so do you mean do I have to change the child's touch listener?

Comment: try this there was an issue in the previous code as it was getting parent of the childRecyclerview and disabling scroll on it.. as childRecyclerView is not direct child of parentRecyclerView you cann't do that directly however you have to explicitly specify the parentRecyclerview

Comment: The child view does scroll now, but not all the time. I have to scroll many times for it to scroll.

Comment: FIXED: I had to do the same thing for each item inside the child recycler view. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to your child RecyclerView , it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Put RecyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(false) after recyclerview.setAdapter inside java code.