# nested recyclerview scroll slowly issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a question because of the recyclerview issue.

My recyclerview structure is like the picture below

[image]

No. 2 and No. 3 are overlapped with the recycler view. No. 3 inside the recycler view,

Recycler view 3 uses a recycler view that scrolls infinitely. When you first load an item, scrolling is normal, but when you add an item later, the recycler view scrolls slowly and stutters.

I looked at the profiler, but the cpu, memory, etc. are not particularly strange.

If you don't use nested recycler view, scrolling works normally, but you have to use recycler view 3 inside recycler view 2 for modularity

I've googled a lot and looked at various materials, but nothing has changed. If you have a solution, could you please share it with me?

No matter how much I think about it, I think there is an issue where the recycler view is not reused.So I checked with the following code, and the log is showing normally.

```
private fun setupRecyclerView() { recyclerView.apply { setRecyclerListener { println("=========== View is reused in $it") } } }
```

From the log, it seems that the viewHolder is reused every time.

Comment: Have you tried with this way ?

recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: Yes I tried that method, but it doesn't work. I am also using setHasFixedSize(true) and after loading the item, scrolling does not work properly, so I adjusted the image size, etc., but the scroll does not work well

Comment: In that recycler view, you are loading very high-resolution images?

Comment: If the image is a problem, the same phenomenon should occur when using only recycler view 2 without using recycler view 3. but it doesn't happen ,I also tried changing the image size, but the scrolling does not work properly.

Comment: Can you help me understand what exactly are you trying to achieve so that we can look for alternative solution, using 3 recyclerview in a same screen doesn't seems to be a good approach

Comment: nitish chaudhary // 
To be precise, it uses two recycler views. 1 is the layout

Comment: in your xml you used many nested layout if used that nested widget which was  unnecessary then you have to remove it

Comment: It's a nested recycler view, but if you use only one recycler view, isn't it a nested recycler view? ...

Comment: To extend what Mehul Tank wrote. Having a lot of nested LinearLayouts can impact performce. Replace LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout to simplify view hierarchy. Talking from personal experience.

Comment: try adding `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` attribute to reccyclerview

Comment: This answer may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973757/nested-recyclerview-not-scrolling  or https://stackoverflow.com/a/32664619/12347940

Comment: Dnyaneshwar Patil // 
 This article has absolutely nothing to do with my problem.